# What are my options for resizing an image in my rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook

### I would honestly appreciate feedback, or an on edit, on what I should change about this post instead of all the down votes. I'm new to web development, and I had an honest question. If this isn't the place to ask it, please point me in the right direction.

I have a Ruby on Rails application where part of the core purpose involves displaying images that I pull from the Facebook Graph API. And I want to be able to display the images in a **uniform size**.

**What I'm hoping I can do:** I'm trying to just store the id of the image from Facebook to my database and resize the image after I pull it from Facebook's servers. I was thinking that this would save on storage costs. I've been looking at the RMagick gem that binds Ruby to the ImageMagick library, specifically their `resize` method.

**Another option I've considered:** I'm thinking about adding a cropping feature. To do this though, I think I would need to set up a storage service, like Amazon's S3. Then I would pull from the image storage service where the cropped images are stored instead of pulling from Facebook and resizing client-side.

Are there any options I might not be considering? And how accurate are my examples to approaches that could be taken.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're taking the wrong approach for asking a question on Stack Overflow. You're asking for opinions, without telling what you've tried and explaining why it didn't work, resulting in a very open-ended question where we have to supply a textbook's worth of information to cover all the possible situations. Instead, you need to be as accurate and exact as possible, detailing what you've done and why it doesn't work for you. THEN we can help you. And, lose the opening paragraph. That'll only act as a red-flag.

Comment: As for pulling in images from Facebook, you'll never achieve the sort of storage savings you want by pulling in the images vs. storing IDs or URLs to images. Also, there are a slew of copyright issues you can encounter by storing the images on your site vs. leaving them on Facebook. *IF* I were to do it, I'd use CSS to set the image size, let the browser scale it during the render to the page, and not try downloading or storing them.

Comment: If you have huge number of image to show, then go with " resize - store - show".  If less then go with on fly process.

Comment: @theTinMan Thank you, I appreciate the feedback and suggestions. I have a much better idea of what I need to do now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a huge number of images to show, then go with "resize - store - show". If less then go with an on-the-fly process.

Here are a few well-known gems that help you process images, but choose according to your requirement:

- CarrierWave
- Paperclip
- Dragonfly
- refile (new gem)

See "[Compare CarrierWave ,Paperclip and Dragonfly in rails](http://praaveenvr.blogspot.in/2014/03/compare-carrierwave-paperclip-and.html)" and "[Refile: Fixing Ruby File Uploads](http://www.elabs.se/blog/68-refile-fixing-ruby-file-uploads)".